# SDN 4.1.2 rich @Relationship doesn't "preload" Set<Relationship> Node properties

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, sdn

Nodes and relationship:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Relationship(type = "WATCHED", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Watched> watchedList = new HashSet<>();


    @Relationship(type = "WATCHED", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Watched> getWatchedList() {
        return watchedList;
    }
}


@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Relationship(type = "WATCHED", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Watched> watchedList = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = "WATCHED", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    public Set<Watched> getWatchedList() {
        return watchedList;
    }
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "WATCHED")
public class Watched {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private User user;

    @EndNode
    private Movie movie;

    private Date date;
    private String comment;
    ...
}
```

A graph example:
[7 WATHCED links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aMfO.png)

When I try something like this with an user: "user.getWatchedList().size()" the result is 0 becouse the watchedList is empty.

BUT, if I execute something like "watchedRepository.findAll()" before, the list loads correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: you're repeating the `@Relationship` annotation on the field , the getter , and the setter method(the `watchlist` annotation), I believe this is redundant , one of them is enough(but I'm not sure if that's the issue though)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not the problem.

Comment: How do you load the `user`?

Comment: I have this in the User repo:

@Query("MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.name = {name} RETURN user")
User findByName(@Param("name") String name);